# String concats in javascript and razor

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to contact strings with variable

```js
 i++;
 var html = '<div> <p>P</p>' +
            '@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item[' + i + '].gram, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Item" })' 
            '</div>';
$('#dynamic_container').append(html);
```

But getting the next error

```
"Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal"
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the JavaScript to add C# code to the RazorPage, it won't work for you. Once the JavaScript is executing, the RazorPage is done executing and will not be re-evaluated after the fact.

Comment: Add the code to HTML and hide it until you need it

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.jGold[' + i + ']` - that's like saying, "I mailed a CD to my friend that lives 1200 miles away, and when they put it in their CD player I can't hear it."    *`@Html` lives with **you** in C#ville.  `i` lives very far away in javascriptopia*.

Comment: @mplungjan I need to add them dynamically

Answer (score 0):

**@Html** is razor syntax and it's compiled by .Net but javascript doesn't understand razor syntax. In order to achieve expected output you can convert your code

**From**

```js
i++;
 var html = '<div> <p>Gold</p>' +
            '@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.jGold[' + i + '].gram, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Gold Gram" })' 
            '</div>';
$('#dynamic_container').append(html);
```

**To**

```js
i++
 var html = '<div> <p>Gold</p>' +
        '<input type="text" name="jGold[' + i + ']" class="form-control" placeholder="Gold Gram" />'+
        '</div>';
$('#dynamic_container').append(html);
```

Above code will do the same work

Answer (score 0):

Use the below printf equivalent of javascript

let num = 10;
console.log(`This is ${num} times!`);